# NullPointException in ListView

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-listview, nullpointerexception

Please have a look at the following code

**activity_form.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Form" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/title" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**list_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listImage"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/star" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Form.java**

```
package com.example.callmanager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Form extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

        ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        String arr[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.branch_list);
        lv.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,R.id.listText,arr));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_form, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
    {

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
                Object[] objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View contentView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent,false);

            TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.listText);
            ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.listImage);

            String arr[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.branch_list);
            tv.setText(arr[position]);

            if(arr[position].equals("Anuradhapura"))
            iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.star);

            return view;

        }

    }

}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Esoft Call Manager</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="menu_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="title"><b>Select a Branch To Call</b></string>

    <string-array name="branch_list">
        <item>Anuradhapura</item>
        <item>Avissawella</item>

    </string-array>

</resources>
```

When I run this code, I get the '`NullPointException`'. I am adding the complete log file here

```
02-08 21:04:01.463: D/dalvikvm(490): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 43K, 53% free 2551K/5379K, external 1949K/2137K, paused 82ms
02-08 21:04:01.713: D/AndroidRuntime(490): Shutting down VM
02-08 21:04:01.713: W/dalvikvm(490): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.callmanager/com.example.callmanager.Form}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at com.example.esoftcallmanager.Form.onCreate(Form.java:24)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-08 21:04:01.733: E/AndroidRuntime(490):  ... 11 more
```

I am adding the folder structure below if it helps

[image]

Why I am getting this error? How to solve this? Please help!

Comment: `here is all the code I have, where is the problem` Pretty awful kind to ask for help...

Comment: You still missed the part where you mark the line in your code where the NullPointer is thrown. To make it short: you posted way more than needed and still missed the important stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by my self. Following edits were required.

**activity_form.xml**

The "id" of the `ListView` should be

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

**Form.java**

It should call the `ListView` in this way

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Inside `getView()`, the initialization of the `TextView` and `ImageView` should be like this

```
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.listText);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.listImage);
```

Note the `view.findViewById()` part.

Comment: Well, although that might work, it is really, really not a solution.  You, most definitely, should not be putting you code into the android: namespace.  Instead, you should remove the "android" prefix from the names of all of your resource ids: R.id.foo, not android.R.id.foo.  In general, your program should compile without importing "android.R".

Answer (score 3):

try this:

change this

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

for:

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Normally they use android.R.id.list when class extends a ListActivity

Comment: Tried. Still the issue is there

Comment: try the inverse put the extends to a ListActivity instead Activity

Comment: Thank you :) I managed to solve the issue by my self. I answered to my same question, including my solution. Thank you for helping me :) +1 from me :)

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

to

```
    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Unless you have an id in your XML in the format of `android:id="@android:id/myID"`, you don't need to use `android.R`. Whenever you use one of your own IDs, you can simply use `R.id.Whatever`

Comment: Tried. Still the issue is there

Comment: Thank you :) I managed to solve the issue by my self. I answered to my same question, including my solution. Thank you for helping me :) +1 from me :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is right here. `ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);` you reference the Id `android.R.id.list` 
however in your layout you reference `android:id="@+id/list"` which creates an Id in the Resources class called list. so you should be referencing `R.id.list` if you debug you will find that the `lv` variable is null because it wasn't found because you referenced the wrong id.

Comment: Tried. Still the issue is there

Comment: yes however after this change you were getting a different NPE, which you noted how to fix in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

I hope it will solve your NPE.

Change it

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

to

```
ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
```

Actually You have defined the list view in the layout **activity_form.xml** have name `list` so you need to write the `R.id.list`.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using your own layout you don't need any more to write `android.R` just remove android and reorganize your class